How to use spring bean in static methods?
My total task: my overall goal is to get the value contained in the header for each rest request and save it somewhere so that I can use it in static methods without passing it to these methods in arguments. It is important that concurrency safety is maintained.
I have a configuration where I defined headerHolder bean. But now it is impossible to use it in static methods, because in this case I always have anonymousUserId field equals null. But at the same time, when using autowiring, it is filled with value. Why does it work so? How can I fix it?
@Configuration
class HeaderInterceptorConfig : WebMvcConfigurer {
    override fun addInterceptors(registry: InterceptorRegistry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(anonymousUserIdInterceptor())
    }

    @Bean
    fun anonymousUserIdInterceptor(): HeaderInterceptor {
        return HeaderInterceptor(headerHolder())
    }

    @Bean
    @Scope(value = WebApplicationContext.SCOPE_REQUEST, proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
    fun headerHolder(): HeaderHolder {
        return HeaderHolder()
    }
}

open class HeaderHolder(
    var anonymousUserId: String? = null
): InitializingBean {
    // If aspects are applied to the class using CGLIB proxy, no-argument constructor is required
    constructor() : this(
        anonymousUserId = null
    )

    override fun afterPropertiesSet() {
        instance = this
    }

    companion object {
        private lateinit var instance: HeaderHolder
        fun get(): HeaderHolder {
            return instance
        }
    }
}

In this class I initialize anonymousUserId field for HeaderHolder
class HeaderInterceptor(
    private val headerHolder: HeaderHolder
) : HandlerInterceptor {
    @Throws(Exception::class)
    override fun preHandle(request: HttpServletRequest, response: HttpServletResponse, handler: Any): Boolean {
        val anonymousUserId = request.getHeader(ANONYMOUS_USER_ID_HEADER_NAME)
        headerHolder.anonymousUserId = anonymousUserId
        return true
    }

    companion object {
        const val ANONYMOUS_USER_ID_HEADER_NAME = "anonymous_user_id"
    }
}

How I get value from HeaderHolder:
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/v1/")
class MyController(
    private val headerHolder: HeaderHolder
) {
    @GetMapping()
    fun getField() {
        println("from autowired holder: ${headerHolder.anonymousUserId}") // value
        println("without autowired holder: ${HeaderHolder.get().anonymousUserId}") // null
    }
}


What is the part of the code where you observe nulls?

thank you. I added details to the question

Still, we miss a part where afterPropertiesSet is called and this is crucial as this is where we initialize the static object. One definitely suspicious part in your code is that you call headerHolder() and anonymousUserIdInterceptor(). This way you don't use the bean created by Spring, but you create a separate instance. Frankly speaking, I'm surprised your code even works with autowiring. I would expect HeaderInterceptor and MyController use different instances of HeaderHolder.

Yes, it is possible to access Spring Beans in a static method.
But your code is complicated; it is not clear what you are trying to do and where you see a null.  Are you using Request Scope on purpose?
Working with little information, my guess it that the first time you access the class it will have just been instantiated.  I suggest you add logging statements to understand when calls are made (if at all) to methods such as the HeaderHolder constructor, HeaderHolder.afterPropertiesSet(), HeaderInterceptor.preHandle(), etc
